# On this integral $\int_0^1 \ln\left(\zeta(s)\right)ds$

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

I am interested in the integral over the log-zeta function$$I=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\zeta(s)\right)ds$$

My attempts:

Sub $u=1-s$ to get $$I=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\zeta(1-u)\right)du=\int_0^1 \ln(\zeta(u))-u\ln2-(u-1)\ln\pi-\ln\left(\sin(\frac{\pi u}{2})\right)-\ln\left(\Gamma(1-u)\right) du$$ This doesn't seem to lead anywhere unfortunately. I also tried to set up  a parameter $a$ as

$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\zeta(s+a)\right)ds$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\zeta'(s+a)}{\zeta(s+a)}ds=\ln\left(\zeta(s+a)\right)|_{s=0}^{s=1}=\ln\left(\zeta(a+1)\right)-\ln\left(\zeta(a)\right)$$ From this point on I am not sure of what to do as integrating with respect to $a$ to recover $I(a)$ does not simplify the integral. If anybody has any idea of how to approach finding a closed form of this integral then please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $\zeta<0$ on this range, you may want to change the problem to $\int_0^1\ln(-\zeta(s))ds$.

Comment: Just playing around a bit with your integral my conjecture is that if $I=\int_0^1 \ln\left(-\zeta(s)\right)ds$ is used, along with the assumption that the real part of all the Riemann Zeta Function zeros is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ then

$$I=-3 \log (A)+2-\frac{5}{12} \log (2)-\frac{\log (\pi )}{4}+2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left( \csc ^{-1}\left(2 \left| \rho _k\right| \right)\sqrt{\left(2 \left| \rho _k\right| \right){}^2-1} -1\right)$$

where $A$ is the Glaisher–Kinkelin constant and $\rho_k$ are the Riemann Zeta Function zeros.

Comment: @JamesArathoon This is very interesting, how were you able to derive this conjecture?

Comment: Given that you are integrating a $\log$ function, I inferred that it might be a good starting point to try to evaluate the integral using a product formula for $\zeta (s)$.  I used the substitution $$-\zeta (s)=\frac{\pi ^{s/2} \prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{s}{\rho _k}\right) \left(1-\frac{s}{\left(\rho _k\right){}^*}\right)}{2 (1-s) \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)}$$. See "Hadamard product" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function. I am not good with Complex Analysis, so hopefully you can take this idea and run with it.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I think this is definitely worth looking into. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Just one further thought. On the assumption that all the zeros of the Riemann Zeta Function have real part $\frac{1}{2}$ the last term involving the zero's is symmetric between $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$, therefore the difference

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \log (-\zeta (s)) \, ds-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \log (-\zeta (s)) \, ds=\frac{1}{24} \left(36 \log (A)+\frac{24 C}{\pi }+\log (4)+3 \log (\pi )\right)$$
appears to have a closed form, where $C$ is Catalan's constant and $A$ is the Glaisher–Kinkelin constant.